# VS Code PowerShell Remote Session looking for local Profile

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, powershell-remoting

I'm running VS Code 1.46.1 on Windows 10 with the PowerShell extension 2020.6.0. Among other settings, I have set

```
[...]
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
"powershell.enableProfileLoading": true,
[...]
```

in VS Code.

Now, whenever I use the PowerShell Integrated Console to establish a PS Remote Session using the following command

`Enter-PSSession -computername ABC.domain.com -Credential (Get-Credential) -Authentication CredSSP`

the PS Session is successfully established, however, as soon as I enter the first command, the remote session loops the following error until I press CTRL + C:

```
The term 'C:\Users\UserOnClient\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\FelTie...ode_profile.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

From the path that is shown, I know that it must come from the client that establishes the remote session. This happens on various remote PCs but doesn't happen when establishing a PS Session from a normal PS or PS ISE.

I can solve the problem by setting

```
[...]
"powershell.enableProfileLoading": false,
[...]
```

however, I rely on my profile being loaded on my local PC.

So I guessed that the problem must be related to the Integrated Console loading some profile when starting (the remote session), so I added

```
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": "-NoProfile",
```

to the VS Code settings.

But that doesn't have any impact at all.

I could also see that, after I have established a remote connection with "powershell.enableProfileLoading": false, when I ticked (enabled) the checkbox for that setting in the Settings-GUI of VS Code, the error messages in the remote session immediately started again.

Any ideas why that happens is appreciated.

Best regards,
felix

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem when using the **PowerShell Integrated Console** in conjunction with `*-PSSession` or `Invoke-Command`.

There's a setting you can disable called `powershell.integratedConsole.showOnStartup` which is set to `true` by default.

When it's `true`, the default shell on startup is the **PowerShell Integrated Console**, which uses `$ENV:UserProfile\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1` as its profile. (this is where it was failing for me)

When this is `false`, you're no longer using the **PowerShell Integrated Console**  and thus the `$profile` falls back to `$ENV:UserProfile\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`. Using this profile, I'm able to execute commands remotely without throwing any exceptions related to the [profile] file.

It's worth nothing that you can also add a new terminal using `+`. Assuming that PowerShell is your default shell, it should start a new console that uses `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` as it's profile.

Cheers!